# Svn non-existent child node

Tags: svn, commit

This should be an extremely simple question, but I find no answers about it anywhere. Maybe someone on here can help...

What's the cause of the problem when committing in SVN, one gets a message saying "Attempted to open non-existent child node 'name'"?

How do I go about fixing it?

Thanks,

Owen.

Comment: Is this a problem with the code base or the working copy?

Comment: Make a patch of your changes, checkout a fresh copy of your project, apply the patch, and try to commit. If you *don't* have any issues doing that, then your initial checkout might be corrupted. If you *do* get that error again, then your SVN server repository might be corrupted

Comment: @SameerSingh A patch? Hmmm.... okay, svn diff to create, but how to apply? I'm using the NetBeans IDE...

Comment: @SameerSingh Thanks for the tip. I think I've fixed it and successfully applied my changes to the code base.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that I must provide an answer in order to give others who may come along to the same problem some handle on a solution.

The problem I was having was that when I attempted to commit changes to SVN from the NetBeans IDE, I was told that I couldn't commit because the commit mechanism "Attempted to open non-existent child node 'name'". I do not have any accurate idea of what this error means, but the tips I was given did put me in a direction where I could find out what was necessary to fix it from within NetBeans, and in this process, I learned a thing or two about what patches are.

So, the solution to my problem was to generate a patch on my working copy against the most recent version in the Subversion repository. I did this from NetBeans by going to the trunk directory of the working copy, then choosing Team->Export Diff Patch from the top menu. I then renamed my working copy so I could check out a new one in its place.

After checking out a new working copy, I selected the trunk of the new working copy from the Favourites menu and chose Team->Apply Diff Patch. This changed, added, and removed files where necessary, but did not delete directories that were made empty where files were deleted. I had to delete these directories manually, but otherwise, applying the changes through a patch worked well.

I committed the new working copy thus altered by the application of the diff patch to the code base without incident. Lovely.

Comment: I'm glad my tip proved helpful. :)